# How to subscribe to real-time updates for a Facebook page's wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time

Facebook's [real-time updates docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) now say that you can get the feed for a page:

> You can subscribe to the page's feed in the same way you subscribe to
>   a user's feed - the subscription topic should be 'user' and the
>   subscription field should be 'feed'

My understanding of this is that I need to post to the graph API to subscribe as such:

```
curl -d \
"object=user&fields=feed&callback_url=$CALLBACKURL&verify_token=$SECRET" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/$PAGEID/subscriptions?access_token=$OAUTHTOKEN"
```

(This is a bash script.)  Here `$CALLBACKURL` is set up correctly following their [example code](https://github.com/facebook/real-time/blob/master/samples/php/callback.php). (At least I think it's correct -- I can successfully add subscriptions with it.) 
The `$OAUTHTOKEN` is the one for my Facebook App.
And the `$PAGEID` is the facebook object id of the page I'd like to get realtime updates for.

When I do this, the call appears to work -- no error message.  My callback gets called.  But I certainly don't get notified when something happens on the page's feed.

So what's missing?  Does the page need to install the app whose oauth token I'm using?  Or do I somehow need to get an oauth token for the *page* itself by logging in as the page?

Comment: Have you achieved what you want?

Comment: Nope.  I haven't dug into it deeply recently, but I also haven't seen any evidence that this is actually possible with the current state of the facebook API.

Comment: Not quite a year later, have you found how to do this?

Answer (score 17):

I do not know if this can help you but I'll tell you where I am for real-time update page feed:

(permissions : manage_page,offline_access,read_stream)

1. your application must be linked to the page (then install the application but not required to have a tab ex. create tab https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/tabs?app_id=APP_ID&method=POST&access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN and delete tab 
   TAB_ID=PAGE_ID.'/tabs/app_'.APP_ID;
   https://graph.facebook.com/TAB_ID?method=DELETE&access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN)

   ```
   function page_access_token($page_id,$access_token){

   $page_token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/" .
   $page_id . "?fields=access_token&" . $access_token;
   $response = file_get_contents($page_token_url);
   $resp_obj = json_decode($response,true);
   $page_access_token = $resp_obj['access_token'];
   return $page_access_token;
   }
   ```

   function page_tabs_create($page_id,$app_id,$page_access_token){

   $page_settings_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" .
   $page_id . "/tabs?app_id=".$app_id."&method=POST&access_token=" . $page_access_token;
   $response = file_get_contents($page_settings_url);
   $resp_obj = json_decode($response,true);
   return $resp_obj;
   }

   function page_tabs_delete($tab_id,$page_access_token){

   $page_settings_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$tab_id."?method=DELETE&access_token=" . $page_access_token;
   $response = file_get_contents($page_settings_url);
   $resp_obj = json_decode($response,true);

   return $resp_obj;
   }
2. Subscription: to subscribe must be like a "user" and therefore object = user fields = feed but you have to add new fields because otherwise it receives the comments and likes the wall so you must add "status" in order to receive the articles posted (my problem is to get other content such as links I have managed to add "link" as fields but I am not receiving notifications when a link is posted)

   $param = array ('access_token' => $ access_token,
   'object' => 'user',
   'fields' => 'feed, status, link'
   'callback_url' => 'http:// ******** fbcallback.php'
   'verify_token' =>'***********',
   'include_values' => 'true');

   POST 
   https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/subscriptions

my English is not very good but I hope it will help you, on my side I'm still looking for really all updates to the wall (links, video ...)

Comment: where I found more information like adding "status" field [http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18048#c40](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18048#c40)

Comment: Thanks Caroline.  This is helpful.  Can you describe in a bit more detail how to add the app to the page without creating a tab?  You send that POST request with which access token?  (You can use the "edit" link to write more in your post instead of adding a comment.)

Comment: Hi @CarolineCraipeau, when I try to do the POST call I get an error "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action", do you know what I have to do?? I request all the permissions and for the users realtime is working well. Thanks!

Comment: I get a `App must have profile tab URL set` when I try to POST to the `/tabs` endpoint

Answer (score 4):

I have been researching on this and i am getting the pushes for pages too.

1. while subscribing make sure that object = user and fields = feed, status is present.
2. Make sure that application is added to your page, then only you will receive the update.
3. Response received from facebook is as below :-

{"entry":[{"id":"***************","uid":"***********","time":1332940650,"changed_fields":["status"]}],"object":"user"}

where ************ is my pageId.

The above push is received on adding a new post , as you can see the changed_feild is status , but when we post on wall the changed_fields comes as feed. Below link helped me in receiving pushes for the page.

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18048

Comment: Hi, are you able to read page feeds even now? As per the latest facebook bug, this is not possible: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/536991969662115?browse=search_50e46a01010542e20755873

Comment: Yes , i am able to retrive the page feeds. On local as well as on production.

Comment: Thanks. How did you do #2 above - Adding application to page?

Comment: Send a Post request to below Facebook Graph Url for adding a tab on page.
"https://graph.facebook.com/pageId/tabs?app_id=appId&access_token=page_access_token

Comment: Thanks a ton. so I add subscription with #1 in my app details, do #2 using above API above (add tab) and then if someone posts a new comment on my facebook page Photo then I should receive an alert, right? Again, thanks much.

Comment: Yes you will receive the alerts. You can upvote my answer though :)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, subscription to real-time update for page/feed doesn't work. 
See: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18048

> > Does the page need to install the app whose oauth token I'm using?

Yes

> > Or do I somehow need to get an oauth token for the page itself by logging in as the page?

If i correctly understand you, you need only **app access_token**
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=your_app_id&client_secret=your_secret&grant_type=client_credentials

Answer (score 2):

I first started reading the docs about real-time updates thinking that it could delivery the actual data. But, as I realized, that's not the purpose.

Real-time updates are just to tell you that something has changed, and once it happens, you can call the api with the conventional method.

Also, seems like there's an error on this part `the subscription topic should be 'user' and the subscription field should be 'feed'`. The subscription topic, actually, should be 'page'. (Have you thought the same?)

And by subscribe on page feed as the same as user feed, means that you can get update notifications, not the data itself.

Not sure if this is a common mistake, but I'm posting it just in case.

--

Currently I'm working on a data mining tool that will need real-time updates. But first, I'm focused on the data itself, so I can't post any examples yet. (I'll edit this answer when implementing this part)

**What I can say about your issue is:**

1) Look that your $PAGEID isn't correct. Actually it's your APPID instead.

2) After subscribing, have your subscription appeared on the list when calling `https://graph.facebook.com/<app-id>/subscriptions?access_token=...` ?

3) With user subscription, does it work? Or is it just with pages?

Comment: _"I first started reading the docs about real-time updates thinking that it could deliver the actual data. But, as I realized, that's not the purpose. Real-time updates are just to tell you that something has changed, and once it happens, you can call the api with the conventional method."_

Makes much more sense now! I don't think the Facebook documentation mentions this very well, if at all.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to set up an endpoint URL that receives both HTTP GET (for subscription verification) and POST (for actual change data) requests from Facebook.

Then you should make a POST to the graph API url `https://graph.facebook.com/<app-id>/subscriptions?access_token=<access_token>` to subscribe, and be ready to handle the verification request.

Then to list subscriptions, just perform a GET request on the same url, `https://graph.facebook.com/<app-id>/subscriptions?access_token=<access_token>`, which returns a JSON-encoded content that lists your subscriptions, up to one per object type.

Answer (score 1):

Before you start waiting for the notifications you should check if the URL is actually being hit or not by FB

Check The Output of Following:

"https://graph.facebook.com/".FACEBOOK_APP_ID."/subscriptions?".$appToken."&client_secret=".FACEBOOK_SECRET;

This shall return the callback_url if set correctly !