# Can't subscribe to page's likes through Real-time updates API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, real-time

I am trying to get updates when the like count of a page my app is on is updated. I am trying to accomplish this by using the [FB Real-time Updates API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/)

When I do a POST, with the object = "page" and the fields = "likes", I get a 400 error with the message '"likes" is an invalid field name'.

object = "page" and the fields = "name" works fine.

The documentation states you are allowed to subscribe to any public attribute.

For those playing the home game, here are the steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Get an OAuth token for your app:

   `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<app_id>&client_secret=<secret>&grant_type=client_credentials`
2. Post to subscription URL:

   `https://graph.facebook.com/<app_id>/subscriptions`

POST Variables:

```
'access_token' => `<access token from step 1>`,
'object' => 'page',
'fields' => 'likes',
'callback_url' => `<a callback url>`,
'verify_token' => 'testingstring123'
```

Comment: to receive notification for a page likes on the post page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367948/how-to-subscribe-to-real-time-updates-for-a-facebook-pages-wall/7384450#7384450

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't supported - from the section 'Real-time Updates' on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/ :

> The Page object supports Real-time Updates for picture, tagged and
>   checkins connections.
>
> Note: Real-time updates are not yet supported for the total number of
>   Page checkins.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this question back from the dead. Since I posted this, they updated their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribing to likes is only for pages that a user likes. The 'likes' object is what pages a user or page likes, not the count of how many people like your page, which cannot be subscribed to.

Comment: From the API documentation: " Note that the page topic is only used for subscribing to changes to public attributes of the page (like name, category, picture etc). This is the same information that is returned by the graph api call https://graph.facebook.com/<page>." I want to know when the "likes" number for the page gets updated. That **is** included in the https://graph.facebook.com/<page> data. Is there somewhere where is says that I can't subscribe to that number?

Comment: I re-read it and its pretty vague.  From their wording, it sounds like it should be available.  I would file a bug at: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: I actually tried that first, but for some reason my bug report just hangs and never gets submitted. Have you had any issues submitting bugs through the new system?