# How to recieve realtime updates from facebook when a user posts in a pages's wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I have a facebook page, and created a test-app and added it to a tab on facebook. The app only shows a iframe for a url.

I have been reading trough https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/ and in the app settings, Real-time updates, I added a subscription for object 'user' and another for object 'page'. Both with field 'feed'.

Testing to a url, works in the dashboard, but whenever a user posts to the page's wall, callback url is never called.

What am I missing?

Comment: I also added app permissions 'manage_pages' and 'read_stream' as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367948/how-to-subscribe-to-real-time-updates-for-a-facebook-pages-wall

But the problem still persists.

Comment: i'm stuck on this same problem. Did you find a solution @cusco ?

Comment: I added some permissions and it now calls backmy url ...