# How to get real time notification when a new comment posted on photo?

Tags: facebook, comments, real-time

I'm in the need for my app to receive notifications whenever someone posts a comment on any photo from a fan page. is this possible at all ? I've found nothing even close.

regards

Comment: If the facebook api doesn't have anything for pushing notifications, you can always poll for them (you wouldn't want to do this as a real-time notification system, however, for a mobile device you'd want a substantial delay between requests).

Answer (score 2):

did you check out facebook [real time updates api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.2). I haven't made much use of this in any productions applications. but do check it out .

> The Graph API has a feature called 'Real Time Updates' that enables
>   apps to subscribe to changes in certain pieces of data. When a change
>   occurs, an HTTP 'POST' request will be sent to a callback URL
>   belonging to that app. This makes apps more efficient, as they know
>   exactly when a change has happened, and don't need to rely on
>   continuous or even periodic Graph API requests when changes aren't
>   happening.

also refer this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367948/how-to-subscribe-to-real-time-updates-for-a-facebook-pages-wall) where they discuss how to subscribe page feed .